# How to use base64 as a custom icon in MapBox react-native?

Tags: react-native, mapbox, openstreetmap

[Currently](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/example/src/components/CustomIcon.js), the way to layer an image on top of the map is:

```
import exampleIcon from '../assets/example.png';

const styles = MapboxGL.StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    iconImage: exampleIcon,
    iconAllowOverlap: true,
    iconSize: 0.5,
  },
});
```

I'd like to use base64 instead. If the library does not allow it, how can I modify it so that it accepts base64?